# Tampermonkey forces HTTPS instead of HTTP - GM_xmlhttprequest()

Tags: http, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am trying to send a GET request to my server, but it cannot handle it.

The problem is that my Tampermonkey script sends the request to `https://123.456.789.012:8000` instead of `http://123.456.789.012:8000`.

My script:

```
        GM_xmlhttpRequest({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://123.456.789.012:8000",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            responseType: "json",
            onload: function(response) {
                console.log("Got response:", response);
            },
            onerror: function(a) {
                console.log("error", a);
            }
        });
```

With connection declared:

```
// @connect http://123.456.789.012:8000
```

Calling it results in an error, where I can see:

```
DONE: 4
HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2
LOADING: 3
OPENED: 1
RESPONSE_TYPE_ARRAYBUFFER: "arraybuffer"
RESPONSE_TYPE_BLOB: "blob"
RESPONSE_TYPE_DOCUMENT: "document"
RESPONSE_TYPE_JSON: "json"
RESPONSE_TYPE_STREAM: "stream"
RESPONSE_TYPE_TEXT: "text"
UNSENT: 0
finalUrl: "https://123.456.789.012:8000/"
readyState: 4
response: undefined
responseHeaders: ""
responseText: ""
responseXML: undefined
status: 0
statusText: ""
```

We can see, that the request was sent to https address.

Obviously, this is just an example address, but works similarly. I tried to send this request by browser (by default through http) and it worked. When doing it by the script, the server receives it, but can't do anything with it.

```
code 400, message Bad request version
```

I found out, that this is because of **https** in the request. So is there any way to force Tampermonkey to send the request through http?

Comment: Check [Chrome settings](https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome)?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Tor Browser and found "HTTPS-Only Mode" - disabling it helped in my problem